# with mongoose, how to add new item and get the array back in the same endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

my endpoint is post operation query with mongoose, I am trying to add new item to an array , I am pushing new item and trying to get back the all array updated as result, the item is correctly pushed to the Db but I am not getting the array updated back from this endpoint, please help, I spend 3 days with this without any result.

```
router.post("/:spotId/newAlbum", [isLoggedIn], async (req, res, next) => {
  const newAlbum = req.body;
  const { spotId } = req.params;
  const id = req.user._id;
  
  try {
   
    const user = await User.findById(id, { password: 0 });
    const spot = await Spot.findOne({ _id: spotId, userId: id }).populate({
      path: "albumsId",
      select: {
        albumName: 1,
      },
    });

    const isAlbumRepeated = spot.albumsId.find(
      (album) => album.albumName === newAlbum.albumName
    );

    if (isAlbumRepeated) {
      return throwError("album with this name is already created", 422)(next);
    }
    
    const savedAlbum = await Album.create({
      ...newAlbum,
      userId: user.id,
      spotId: spot._id,
    });
    const savedAlbumId = savedAlbum._id;

    await Spot.findByIdAndUpdate(spotId, { $push: { albumsId: savedAlbumId } });

    const result = await Album.findAndUpdate({ spotId: spotId }, { $push: { savedAlbum } });
    
    const finalResult = await Album.find({ spotId: spotId });
 
 
    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      data: finalResult,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return throwError("error adding album!", 422)(next);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing the return statement

```
return res.status(200).json({
```

Comment: nop, doesn't make any difference.thanks anyway. @DanielDuong